# SolidDB in Spring Boot + JPA

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, ibm-soliddb

I want to use SolidDb in Spring Boot application with JPA. There is almost nothing on google about this database and I could not found example of implementation with JPA. So my question is: Is it possible to use SolidDb with JPA or Hibernate(I could not find Dialect) and If there is some example of it please share it.

Comment: Its easy to vote down :) Its harder to answer...